# What is the conclusion of the passage

Tags: reading, comprehension

> A single short story can suggest a desired response from the reader. It is a difficult task, though, to create
>   a world within a single short story and then repeat this world again in other stories while maintaining a
>   consistent flow of ideas. Many authors prefer to use the same setting, indeed, often the same characters in
>   each story. Isabel Allende’s Diez Cuentos’ de Eva
>   Luna comes to mind. In these stories, Allende uses the small town of Agua Santa as the setting for the entire
>   collection.
>
> Woman Hollering Creek is a collection of short stories by Sandra Cisneros. Rather than using the same
>   characters or setting throughout the collection, Cisneros takes a different approach to relating her stories to
>   one another. Much of the burden, in fact, is placed on
>   the reader, for the characters change each time, as does the setting. 
>   Furthermore, while the characters are
>   largely Mexican American immigrant women, each character presents a distinct style and literary voice. **What
>   *these* works have in common is more intuitive; mood, circumstance, time, tone, and imagery all play a role in
>   creating the world in which the stories take place**

What does ***these*** refers to? Are they Sandra's short stories or both of the writers ?

Comment: I would suspect "these" refers to Cisneros' works because the sentence in which it appears is part of the same paragraph describing Cisneros' works. If the sentence were part of a new paragraph, I would suggest that it refers to both authors' works.

Comment: @Dog Lover Agreed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about interpretation of discourse grammar (more properly asked on Lit?)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly refers to **"Woman Hollering Creek"**, that is the collection of short stories by Sandra Cisneros.

The reason for it is where it appears in the text. It comes after the statement that her works are *different*. And this sentence with the words "these works" describe their common characteristics.

Comment: There is also the fact that the second 'these' is contrasted with the first by being italicised. And the fact that it is placed in the second paragraph, rather than in a third.